# How to import/export a module based on browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, react-hook-form

I'm trying to import a module only for IE11, https://react-hook-form.com/faqs/, and then re-import it in another file.

```
// utils/index.js
let loadModule;

if (isIE11) {
    loadModule = require('react-hook-form/dist/index.ie11');
} else {
    loadModule = require('react-hook-form');
}

module.exports = { ...loadModule };

// import it in another file

import {useForm} from './utils/index';
...
```

The question would be if this is possible to do it with import/export, and if my code would be the proper way to handle this case

Answer (score 0):

> The question would be if this is possible to do it with `import`/`export`, and if my code would be the proper way to handle this case

Not `import`/`export` *declarations*, no. But it's possible with [*dynamic import*](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) (`import()`, part of ES2020) and [top-level `await`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) (currently Stage 3, but likely to advance very soon and be in ES2021).

`utils/index.js`:

```
const { useForm } = await import(
    isIE11
        ? 'react-hook-form/dist/index.ie11'
        : 'react-hook-form'
);

export { useForm };
```

Another file:

```
import { useForm } from './utils/index';
```

Both are well-supported in modern bundlers, and since you're dealing with IE11, you must be dealing with bundlers if you're using JavaScript modules rather than `require`.

Comment: FWIW, I cover `import()` and top-level `await` in Chapters 13 and 19 (respectively) in my new book, *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.